# How can I loop through twig data

Tags: php, loops, twig, render, frontend

I have a problem with twig.

This is my array from the database:

```
databaseData array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "item0"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "item1"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "item2"
    [3]=>
    string(14) "item3"
    [4]=>
    string(17) "item4"
    [5]=>
    string(13) "item5"
    [6]=>
    string(12) "item6"
    [7]=>
    string(9)  "item7"
    [8]=>
    string(12) "item8"
    [9]=>
    string(6)  "item9"
  }
  ["amount"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [6]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [7]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [8]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [9]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
  ["path"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "/images/item0.png"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "/images/item1.png"
    [2]=>
    string(25) "/images/item2.png"
    [3]=>
    string(26) "/images/item3.png"
    [4]=>
    string(29) "/images/item4.png"
    [5]=>
    string(25) "/images/item5.png"
    [6]=>
    string(24) "/images/item6.png"
    [7]=>
    string(21) "/images/item7.png"
    [8]=>
    string(18) "/images/item8.png"
    [9]=>
    string(18) "/images/item9.png"
  }
}
```

And this is how i pass it into twig:

```
$data['name'] = $this->factory->createHomeController()->allNamesFromDatabase);
            $data['amount'] = $this->factory->createHomeController()->allAmountsFromDatabase();
            $data['path'] = $this->factory->createHomeController()->allImagePathsFromDatabase();

return $this->twigEnv->render('index.twig', array(
               'data' => $databaseData,
               ));
```

in the index.twig I want to show the picture, amount and name in one ""

```
{% for item in data['path'] %}
{% for item0 in data['name'] %}
    <img class="" src="{{ item }}" alt="" height="200" width="200">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried a lot, but still can't figure out how I get this fixed :(

Would be nice if someone can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mimic a `foreach ($data as $key => $value) { .. }` in twig by doing :

```
  {% for index,path in data.path %}
    <img class="" src="{{ path }}" alt="" height="200" width="200" />
    <h1>{{ data.name[index] }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
  {% for path in data.path %}
    <img class="" src="{{ path }}" alt="" height="200" width="200">
  {% endfor %}

  {% for name in data.name %}
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: does not work for me :( i tried that similar 1 hour ago

Comment: still not working :( I edited my php code in the question as well, for more info

Comment: @aikn, ok, now I see.

Comment: Now i have every name and every img on the frontpage, thanks!
But now i have the problem that they are not in one section, I want the correct name under the correct img.